# How to align text differently inside a single inline element with CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment, inline

This should be interesting. Here's what I'm trying to do with CSS:

1. The words "An Example Alignment" should be in a single `<h1>` element.
2. The word "Alignment" should be on the second line (easy with a `<br />` tag).
3. The word "An" should be smaller than the other words (easy with a `<span>` tag).

[image]

So we have:

```
<h1><span>An</span> Example <br />Alignment</h1>
```

**But here's the catch:**

- I would also like to align the first letters of the 2nd and 3rd words with each other vertically, and that's where I run into problems.

Here's what it should *look* like: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/H2Pzr/

But that's an ugly solution as there are two `<h1>` elements.

Any ideas of how to do this with CSS by keeping the HTML the same? Very curious to hear. Thank you in advance.

*P.S. I could also put "An" into a separate `<span>`, but I would prefer to keep everything in a single `<h1>`.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two span classes in the same H1 tag:

```
<h1>
    <span class="small-text">An</span> Example 
    <span class="line-two">Alignment</span>
</h1>
```

Then update your CSS accordingly:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

span.small-text {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.line-two{
    display:block;
    margin-left: 31px;
}
```

You don't even need the `<br />` since you can just display the second span as `display:block;`
Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/H2Pzr/6/

Comment: Great idea Andy, thanks! I'll do just that to avoid the <br /> tag :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the padding by using two `display:inline-block` spans, to make sure the right margin is always exactly the same (font width varies, depending on the in-use font face).

```
<h1>
    <span class="padding">An</span> Example <br>
    <span class="padding"></span> Alignment
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.padding {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Just beware that IE doesn't always use `inline-block` the right way (although in this case it should).

### Update

An even better solution: http://jsfiddle.net/H2Pzr/9/

Use the `table-cell` display of elements to automatically put them in two columns:

HTML:

```
<h1>
<span class="first">An</span>
<div class="second">
    Example <br>
    Alignment
</div>
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.first {
    display:table-cell;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #444;
}
.second {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting table-cell solution, but IE7 (and the one that will remain nameless) don't support it. Might be a problem...

Answer (score 1):

use two span with different class see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Pzr/3/)

```
<h1><span class="first">An</span> Example <br>
    <span class="second">Alignment</span>
    </h1>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! For some reason I thought that a span can't have margins separate from its parent element. Glad you cleared that up for me. Much appreciated!

Comment: What are your thoughts on using the `<br>` tag with semantics in mind? Andy (see above) suggested setting CSS `display:block` instead — probably better, no? Which is the best solution to make sure it's compatible on older browsers such as IE6?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (minimal elements!)

```
<h1>Example <br>Alignment</h1>​

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 31px;
}

h1:before
{
    content: 'An  ';
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: -31px;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks! Really clean. Any pitfalls? IE6?

Comment: @Baumr if you like any answer, then I believe you already have enough rep to vote them up!

Comment: Shalom :) But adding text via CSS hides it from crawlers :(